# Problem with Intuitive meaning of derivative

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

The derivative of a function in some variable is the rate of change of that function to the change of that variable. Suppose there is a phenomena in nature such that amount of a parameter, say mass, of that phenomena is specified by time (in year) by the following function

$$f(t) = 2t^3 + t - 1$$

It means in the third year I expect to have $2\times 3^3+3-1 = 56$ units of that phenomena. If the derivative of function of mass in time shows the rate of change for each year, so the mass of that phenomena in the third year must be the sum of the changes of masses in the current moment and the first and the seconds years. So there must be

$$
f(3) = \sum_{i=0}^{2}f^{'}(i) = \sum_{i=0}^{2}6i^2+1 = 1 + 7 + 25 = 33
$$

and $33 \neq 56$ which confuses me. I would be appreciated if you explain what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you take the graph of a function $f$, then for each point $x$ the derivative describes the tangent of $f$ at $x$. A horizontal tangent usually gives a max or min point. Consider also saddle points.

Comment: @Wuestenfux what is wrong with my problem?

Comment: @Wuestenfux actually I was asking about intuitive meaning of that concept!

Comment: You use a function which is continous in time $t$. But then you want to apply it to annual growth, which is discrete. Now it is possible to this is, however you should be more careful. Begin by making a tabel of function values for $t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4....$. You can then read the annual growth by taking differences.

Comment: The derivative estimates a step in the output given a small step in the input, in terms of the small step $f(x+dx)\approx f(x)+f'(x)dx$. Note: assumed here the step could be transfered to the output directly.

Comment: Once you have computed the annual growth rates, you can compare them to the derivative of $f$, which symbolizes the instantanious growth rate. These two concepts are not the same, as you will notice.

Comment: Thank you @M.Wind , the growth of mass is increasing by time at every moment which is continuous, not at some specific times

Comment: Your sum is the equivalent of attempting to determine how far you drove in three hours by checking your speedometer once per hour.

Comment: @Bungo very good example, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you found that sum formula from, but its definitely wrong. However, if we use another handy tool of calculus, the integral, we can make a more meaningful expression$$f(3)=f(0)+\int_0^3f'(t)dt$$Where you went wrong was assuming that derivative meant change in $f$ between unit time intervals. Rather, it is the *instantaneous* rate of change, the limit of the rate of change as you continue to reduce the size of the interval.

Comment: Integral of derivative of a function equals to the original function plus a constant $C$. Actually nothing happened here

Comment: That would be if you are taking an indefinite integral. I think you're missing the bigger picture.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my post

Comment: Yes I understand what was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly mention the derivative gives you the change per time. In order to get the absolute change for a small time interval $\Delta t$ you have to multiply the derivative with this Intervall $f'(t)\Delta t$. Note that now also the units are correct. Now if you sum over this changes up to $t=56$, you would get $33$. The problem is that $f‘(t)$ is not constant. This means that $\Delta t$ has to be infinitesimally small. Taking the limit of the resulting sum we obtain the integral as in Rushabh Mehta‘s answer. Let $\Delta t=\frac t n$, then
$$
f(t)=f(0)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n f'\bigg(k\cdot\frac t n\bigg)\cdot\frac t n=f(0)+\int_0^t f'(t)\,\text dt
$$
The sum is called Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^2 t'(i) = t'(0) + t'(1) + t'(2)$

[image]

Or the area of the green bars illustrated above.

The concept you are going after, that the area under the curve $f'(t)$ evaluated from from 0 to 3 should equal $f(3).$

But you still need to adjust for the constant term in $f(t)$ that is:

$\int_0^3 f'(t)\ dt = f(3) - f(0)\\
f(3) = f(0) + \int_0^3 f'(t)\ dt$

But the bigger piece that you are missing is that in evaluating at as you have, you have the lower sums, and you are missing the red areas.

Since $f'(t)$ is monotonic, You can say

$t'(0) + t'(1) + t'(2)\le f(3) - f(0) \le t'(1) + t'(2) + f'(3)$

And then you could make a increasingly fine partitions, until you squeeze the value in the middle.